# Drag and drop in jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-file-upload

I use jQuery File Upload to send file on my server.

I have problem, on my page I would like use two independents drag and drop areas. So when I created two input, and I click Add files everything is OK. File is added to specific input.
But when I drag and drop file on my page, the file is added to two inputs.

[image]

I know what is wrong. Look on example. Whole page is area where you can add file. How can I 'drop -and drag ' file to specific area, not whole page
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: use diferent ids/classes and bind the upload on each of them

Comment: I have diferrent ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer in documentation

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Drop-zone-effects